# I see no way to draw Polygons with Google Maps API for IOS

Tags: ios, google-maps-mobile

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/?goback=%2Egde_73521_member_195822698
Polylines can be drawn, but no polygons with IOS API?

Am I missing something?

Comment: you have missed something: to provide more info: where in ios is a google maps API? i dont know one. did you mean MKMapView?

Comment: Further you should study what is the difference between a polygon and a filled polygon. if you can draw a polyline, then you can draw a polygon, too. because a polygon is nothing more than a polyline with same start and end point.

Comment: I know the difference between a polygon and a polyline, thank you. Here is the API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/?goback=%2Egde_73521_member_195822698

Comment: upvote from me, thanks for the lib, i will need that for my app.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a really old thread but it took a while for me to find this so I thought I'd share what I am now using since the question remains open.

First assign a `GMSMutablePath` for all polygon points using lat/long - the below example outlines the Coast of Suffolk, UK:

```
GMSMutablePath *poly = [GMSMutablePath path];
[poly addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.506191, 1.83197)];
[poly addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.05249, 1.650696)];
[poly addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.92225, 1.321106)];
[poly addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.996719, 1.219482)];
[poly addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.049112, 1.244202)];
[poly addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.197507, 1.334839)];
[poly addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.519564, 1.801758)];
```

Then create the `GMSPolygon` using the path, set it's appearance properties and assign it to the map!

```
GMSPolygon *polygon = [GMSPolygon polygonWithPath:poly];
polygon.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.25 blue:0 alpha:0.3];
polygon.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor];
polygon.strokeWidth = 5;
polygon.map = self.googleMap;
```

Hope it helps someone out there..